# How to display a Image stored on Google Cloud Storage in a Google WebApp without making it public?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a calendar add-on using Google Apps Script and CardService. It has few input boxes and a submit button. On submitting the information, a webapp is called having an image. The webapp is created using Google Apps Script.
This image is saved in Google Cloud storage bucket. I have to make the image accessible to all in the organization without making it public. How can I achieve this ?

The entire code is too extensive, hence sharing only the code relevant to the image.

```
let imgAction = CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('openImage')
      .setParameters({cldImg: JSON.stringify(imgPath), preview: 'false'})

let submitButton = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Submit')
      .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
      .setBackgroundColor("#00b300")
      .setOnClickAction(imgAction)
      
let subBtn = CardService.newButtonSet()
      .addButton(submitButton);   
      
      
function openImage(){
 return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
      .setUrl(imageUrl+'?param1='+param1+'&param2='+param2+'&param3='+param3)
      .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY)
      .setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.RELOAD))
      .build();   
}
```

I tried following -

1. Using Urlfetch to obtain the imageUrl. This is creating a re-direct url and throwing below error -

```
Exception: Request failed for https://script.google.com returned code 302. Truncated server response: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
    at openFloorMap(formActions:386:31)
```

Comment: Here's something you can try. Load the image from your bucket, convert it to a data-uri, and then pass that data-uri to the `setUrl()` method. `CardService` does support data-uris in some cases so it might work for your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I view images from a Google Photo Library

```
function listImagesDialog1() {
  var token = '';
  var html = '';
  var n = 0;
  do {
    var params = { muteHttpExceptions: true, headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    var url = Utilities.formatString('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems?pageSize=100%s', (token != null) ? "&pageToken=" + token : "");
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    var js = JSON.parse(resp.getContentText());
    for (var i = 0; i < js.mediaItems.length; i++) {
      let dt = new Date(js.mediaItems[i].mediaMetadata.creationTime);
      let date = Utilities.formatDate(dt,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMM dd, yyyy");
      html += Utilities.formatString('<br />%s - File Name: %s<br />MediaItemId: %s<br />Width: %s Height: %s Date: %s<br /><img src="%s" width="265"/>', ++n, js.mediaItems[i].filename, js.mediaItems[i].id, js.mediaItems[i].mediaMetadata.width, js.mediaItems[i].mediaMetadata.height, date, js.mediaItems[i].baseUrl);
    }
    token = js.nextPageToken;
  } while (token != null);
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(1200).setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Images')
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

Create a webapp with it and put it onto a shared drive and only give access to those who you wish to share it with